# How to convert a recursive multidimensional array to a straight multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have search for a solution for this but couldn't find anything giving me a "straight" multidimensional array back. Flatten is probably not the solution as long as i want to preserve the original sub structure?

In additional i want to summarize qty when the key is repeating.

This is my original array:

```
Array
(
    [60002] => Array
        (
            [50001] => Array
                (
                    [50002] => Array
                        (
                            [10001] => Array
                                (
                                    [flag] => B
                                    [qty] => 1
                                )
                            [10002] => Array
                                (
                                    [flag] => B
                                    [qty] => 1
                                )
                            [10003] => Array
                                (
                                    [flag] => B
                                    [qty] => 2
                                )
                            [flag] => M
                            [qty] => 1
                        )
                    [flag] => M
                    [qty] => 1
                )
            [flag] => G
            [qty] => 1
        )
    [10001] => Array
        (
            [flag] => B
            [qty] => 1
        )
)
```

What i basically want is to create a new array looking like this:

```
Array 
(
    [10001] => Array
        (
            [flag] => B
            [qty] => 2
        )
    [10002] => Array
        (
            [flag] => B
            [qty] => 1
        )
    [10003] => Array
        (
            [flag] => B
            [qty] => 2
        )
    [50001] => Array
        (
            [flag] => M
            [qty] => 1
        )
    [50002] => Array
        (
            [flag] => M
            [qty] => 1
        )
    [60002] => Array
        (
            [flag] => G
            [qty] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? Show us your attempt!

Comment: Yes, it's totally doable. No, there's not a built-in function for this incredibly specific use-case.

Comment: Well, i have absolutely tried! ..but ends up in a mess. Thought it would be better with a clean question :)

Comment: How much will the arrays change in production use?  Is this fixed?  or will the number of elements not be constant?

Comment: The array will absolutely change in production, both in size and depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested.

The key is `intval()`
.

```
$value['qty'] += intval($newArray[$key]['qty']);
```

If the `[$key]['qty']` does not exist the intval() will return a zero.  This is much faster than using an `if else` to check if a `[$key]['qty']` already exists.

The only possible problem I could anticipate is if the Flag value is different when the key value is the same:

```
[10001] => Array(
      [flag] => M
      [qty] => 1
 ),
[10001] => Array(
       [flag] => B
       [qty] => 1
 )
```

When this is an issue I resolve the priority with a logic table in an array.

```
$priority['M']['B'] = 'M'
$priority['B']['M'] = 'M'
$priority['']['M'] = 'M'
$priority['M'][''] = 'M'
$priority['B'][''] = 'B'
$priority['B'][''] = 'B'
settype($newArray[$key]['flag'],'string'); 
[$newArray[$key]['flag'] = $priority[$value['flag']][$newArray[$key]['flag']]
```

**Data:**

```
$array = array('60002' => Array('50001' => Array('50002' => Array('10001' => Array('flag' => 'B','qty' => 1),'10002' => Array('flag' => 'B','qty' => 1),'10003' => Array('flag' => 'B','qty' => 2),'flag' => 'M','qty' => 1),'flag' => 'M','qty' => 1),'flag' => 'G','qty' => 1),'10001' => Array('flag' => 'B','qty' => 1));
```

**PHP**

```
$newArray = array();
getValues($data);
function getValues($array){
  global $newArray;
  foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_numeric($value['qty'])) {
      $value['qty'] += intval($newArray[$key]['qty']);
      $newArray[$key] = array('flag'=>$value['flag'],'qty'=>$value['qty']);
    }
    if (gettype($value) != 'array'){return;}
    getValues($value);
  }
}
ksort($newArray);
var_export($newArray);
```

**Result:**

```
array (
  10001 => 
  array (
    'flag' => 'B',
    'qty' => 2,
  ),
  10002 => 
  array (
    'flag' => 'B',
    'qty' => 1,
  ),
  10003 => 
  array (
    'flag' => 'B',
    'qty' => 2,
  ),
  50001 => 
  array (
    'flag' => 'M',
    'qty' => 1,
  ),
  50002 => 
  array (
    'flag' => 'M',
    'qty' => 1,
  ),
  60002 => 
  array (
    'flag' => 'G',
    'qty' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Just added a sort so it is exact to what you wanted.

Comment: This looks absolutely promising, very narrative and clean!
I have tested it and it does exactly what i wanted.
Have to do some serious testing on my production code but accept this as the answer.
Thanks for the effort (everyone) for helping me with this.

Comment: "The only possible problem I could anticipate is if the Flag value is different when the key value is the same"
Thank you for taken this into consideration!
I don't think this will happen but absolutely something to keep in mind, and of course nice having a solution for!

Comment: Btw, sorry for not being able to giving you a vote. Don't have enough reputation for that yet..

Comment: I just gave you a little help to get you there.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
function extractArray(array $source, array &$destination, $originalIndex)
{
    foreach($source as $index => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
            extractArray($value, $destination, $index);
        else
        $destination[$originalIndex][$index] = $value;
    }
}

$test = array(
    60002 => array
    (
        50001 => array
            (
                50002 => array
                    (
                        10001 => array
                            (
                                'flag' => 'B',
                                'qty' => 1
                            ),
                        10002 => array
                            (
                                'flag' => 'B',
                                'qty' => 1
                            ),
                        10003 => array
                            (
                                'flag' => 'B',
                                'qty' => 2
                            ),
                        'flag' => 'M',
                        'qty' => 1
                    ),
                'flag' => 'M',
                'qty' => 1
            ),
        'flag' => 'G',
        'qty' => 1
    ),
10001 => array
    (
        'flag' => 'B',
        'qty' => 1
    )
);

$new = array();
foreach($test as $index => $value)
    extractArray($value, $new, $index);

var_dump($new);
die();
```

Comment: This is giving me exactly the array i want, but it don't summarize qty when the key is repeating. 
Should give [qty]=>2 for 10001

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive approach to iterate over all levels of the array. For each item you check that it is an array and if it has any of the keys you want checked, add the array consisting of the found attributes.

```
function flattenArray($array, $keysToCheck) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $item) {
        // check if the current array item is a candidate to
        // be added to the flattened array
        if(is_array($item)) {
            $foundAttributes = array();
            foreach($item as $key=>$value) {
                if(in_array($key, $keysToCheck) {
                    $foundAttributes[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
            // we found at least one matching attribute
            if(count($foundAttributes)) {
                array_push($result, $foundAttributes);
            }
            // recursively go to the next level and merge the results from there
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenArray($item, $keysToCheck);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

// usage example
$flattenedArray = flattenArray($originalArray, array('flag', 'qty'));
```

The above solution allows you to customise it for other type of objects, by passing different `$keysToCheck` arguments to the function.

If you also need the flattened array sorted, you can use [usort()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to achieve this.

Please pardon any syntax errors, I don't have a PHP interpreter at hand.